# Proposition $3.1$ of Chapter $6$ of Riemannian Geometry by Do Carmo

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I would like to know how the previous comment in the proof gives the highlighted term below in the proof of the Ricci's equation.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\langle B(S_\eta X,Y),\zeta\rangle = \langle S_\zeta S_\eta X, Y\rangle$ almost by definition of shape operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment along with the fact that the shape operator is self-adjoint (used in the third line):

\begin{align*}
 \langle \overline R(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle &= \langle R^\perp(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle - \langle B(S_\eta X,Y),\zeta \rangle + \langle B(X,S_\eta Y),\zeta\rangle\\
 &= \langle R^\perp(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle -  \langle S_\zeta S_\eta X,Y \rangle + \langle S_\zeta X, S_\eta Y\rangle\\
 &= \langle R^\perp(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle -  \langle S_\zeta S_\eta X,Y \rangle + \langle S_\eta S_\zeta X, Y\rangle\\
 &= \langle R^\perp(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle +  \langle S_\eta S_\zeta X - S_\zeta S_\eta X,Y \rangle \\
 &= \langle R^\perp(X,Y)\eta,\zeta\rangle +  \langle [S_\eta, S_\zeta] X,Y \rangle \\
\end{align*}